How can i make my jpg logo file fit better in android studio
i have this ic_launcher.xml file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>

how can i make my logo fit better (a part of it cut's off)?
i searched all over the internet but sadly nothing

Edit it in an image editing program, how else would you do it? The official Android developer site has a section about icons with a diagram of the safe zone for an icon image file. You should be using png instead of jpg.jpg is for big photos. The compression is not well suited for an icon.

thx............ :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here is another solution which I feel is more sensible for those working on Android Studio:
Expand the project root folder in the Project View
Right Click on the app folder
In the Context Menu go to New->Image Asset
In the pop up that appears select the the new logo you would like to have(image/clip art/text).
If you were selecting the image radio button (as is the default choice), if you clicked on the 3-buttons to show the path tree to locate your .png image file, most probably you might not be seeing it, so drag it from the Windows Explorer (if Windows) and drop it in the tree, and it will appear and ready for being selected.
That is it! You have a new logo for you app now.
